# How come there are so many Dragon Slayers?

Tags: fairy-tail

In *Fairy Tail*, they say that Dragon Slayers are really rare, but it seems like there's more of them than most other kinds of magic. The closest amount of one kind of magic is maker magic; there are 5 people who are shown using it (Lyon, Gray, Ur, Ultear, and Rufus). It's kinda the same thing with Celestial Wizards, they say there aren't many of them but there are 4 in the show (Lucy, Angel, Yukino, and Hisui. There's also Karen who died 3 years ago and I think there's more in the anime during the Clock Arc, but I don't think that is in the manga).

I kind of get why the Celestial Wizards were likely to interact because they were needed for stuff, but if there aren't many Dragon Slayers, wouldn't it make more sense for them to run into more of any other kind of wizard than for 7 Dragon Slayers to just happen to find each other? Other than when they run into Leon, they never meet anyone with the same magic as anyone else in the guild except Celestial Wizards and Dragon Slayers.

Answer (score 2):

There being so many Dragon Slayers despite it being a Lost Magic is an element central to Fairy Tail's plot. Dragon Slayer Magic is extremely rare since the only modern way to learn it is to embed Dragon Lacryma into the body as Laxus, Cobra and God Serena did. Natsu, Wendy, Gajeel, Rogue and Sting are completely different cases as they were taught by dragons themselves more than 400 years in the past and were later send through time to year 777 as part of [The 400 Year Plan](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/The_400_Year_Plan). Back in the past, Dragon Slaying magic was far more common.

Comment: I already knew all that what I was asking is more why do they run into so many dragon slayers if there aren't many whereas you mostly were saying how there are so few

Comment: @user30104 It is so rare in year 777 because there is no way to accomplish it without implanting dragon lacrima. 400 years ago, the kids were trained by dragons, and as dragons were still around, it wasn't as rare. They were then sent into the same year in the future, and so they are the cases that we know of.

Answer (score 0):

Fairy Tail has run into so many more people then dragon slayers and celestial wizards, but if you were to do a scene for every single one, that would take eons.

If you were to write a story of someone right now, would you write down every single person they met? Of course not, you would write only the notable ones and the ones that got them on the path they are on.

Being that path they are on is to take down Acnologia and Zeref. The arcs that are written are the ones to that effect, discount filler ones of course.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is because the plot is surrounding dragon slayers. OFC the story is going to introduce as many of the known ones as possible. You say why are there so many, there arent, there are a handful, but since the story is focused on dragon slayers, its only natural to feel like they are popping up everywhere.

Its like if youre a doctor, at some hospital convention, lots of other people will be there too, but ofc, youll be looking for other doctors. Ya know?